# Dictionary with csv files is not reading each column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary

I created a dictionary with several dataframes using the following code:

```
dataframes = {}
csv_root = Path(".")

for csv_path in csv_root.glob("*.csv"):
    key = csv_path.stem  # the filename without the ".csv" extension
    dataframes[key] = pd.read_csv(csv_path, skiprows=1,delim_whitespace=True)
```

However, it is not recognizing all the columns contained within each dataframe, which are divided by a comma "," in csv format. Instead of recognizing 7 columns, it only recognizes 2.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is it because you're passing `delim_whitespace=True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) :

> **delim_whitespacebool**, default False
>
> Specifies whether or not whitespace (e.g. ' ' or '    ') will be used as the sep. Equivalent to setting sep='\s+'. If this option is
> set to True, nothing should be passed in for the delimiter parameter.

By setting this option, you are indicating to pandas to split your csv file on whitespaces rather than on commas (default behavior).

Try with

```
pd.read_csv(csv_path, skiprows=1)
```